# How to create docfx documentation from Typescript code?

Tags: typescript, documentation, docfx

I have found this page on docfx site https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/universalreference/gen_doc_for_ts.html and it mentions Type2docfx npm library. But what I found is that the latest version of Type2docfx doesn't work with the latest TSDoc & Typescript.

Also as per their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/docascode/type2docfx) Type2docfx is not in active development, so is there any alternative to generate docfx based documentation from Typescript.

If I use previous versions of TSDoc then Type2docfx works, but I lose many key features of TSDoc like only generating documentation of exported modules in the index.ts file.